# Installing svn on centos got dependency error

Tags: svn, centos

I successfully logged in as a root user through SSH (a cent-OS system) now I am installing svn and got following output

```
[root@SERVERIP ~]# yum install mod_dav_svn subversion
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mod_dav_svn.x86_64 0:1.6.11-9.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-9.el6_4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaprutil-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-9.el6_4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libapr-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-9.el6_4.x86_64
---> Package subversion.x86_64 0:1.6.11-9.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libneon.so.27()(64bit) for package: subversion-1.6.11-9.el6_4.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package apr.x86_64 0:1.3.9-5.el6_2 will be installed
---> Package apr-util.x86_64 0:1.3.9-3.el6_0.1 will be installed
---> Package mod_dav_svn.x86_64 0:1.6.11-9.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-9.el6_4.x86_64
---> Package neon.x86_64 0:0.29.3-3.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpakchois.so.0()(64bit) for package: neon-0.29.3-3.el6_4.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mod_dav_svn.x86_64 0:1.6.11-9.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-9.el6_4.x86_64
---> Package pakchois.x86_64 0:0.4-3.2.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-9.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
sendmail-cf-8.14.4-8.el6.noarch has missing requires of sendmail = ('0', '8.14.4', '8.el6')
```

Don't know what I am doing wrong. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
$ find / -name "yum.conf"
$ nano /etc/yum.conf
```

Remove `httpd*` from this line:

> exclude=apache* bind-chroot courier* dovecot* exim* filesystem httpd*
>   mod_ssl* mydns* mysql* nsd* perl* php* proftpd* pure-ftpd* ruby*
>   spamassassin* squirrelmail*

Save and close yum.conf, install mod_dav_svn

```
yum install mod_dav_svn
```